# ANTLR print index (in the line) of unrecognized char

Tags: antlr, antlr3

In my ANTLR grammar, I have the following statements:

```
@lexer::apifuncs
{
    LEXER->rec->displayRecognitionError = recognition_error;
}

@parser::apifuncs
{
    RECOGNIZER->displayRecognitionError = recognition_error;
}
```

The C function "recognition_error" (to process recognition errors thrown by ANTLR) is defined as the following:

```
void recognition_error(pANTLR3_BASE_RECOGNIZER recognizer, pANTLR3_UINT8 *token_list)
{

    pANTLR3_EXCEPTION           ex;
    pANTLR3_LEXER               lexer;
    pANTLR3_PARSER              parser;
    pANTLR3_TREE_PARSER         tparser;
    pANTLR3_INPUT_STREAM        ins;
    pANTLR3_INT_STREAM          is;
    pANTLR3_COMMON_TOKEN_STREAM cts;
    pANTLR3_TREE_NODE_STREAM    tns;

    if (recognizer->type == ANTLR3_TYPE_LEXER)
    {
        lexer = (pANTLR3_LEXER) (recognizer->super);
        ins = lexer->input;
        is = ins->istream;
    }
    else if (recognizer->type == ANTLR3_TYPE_PARSER)
    {
        parser  = (pANTLR3_PARSER) (recognizer->super);
        cts = (pANTLR3_COMMON_TOKEN_STREAM)(parser->tstream->super);
        is = parser->tstream->istream;
    }
    else if (recognizer->type == ANTLR3_TYPE_TREE_PARSER)
    {
        tparser = (pANTLR3_TREE_PARSER) (recognizer->super);
        tns = tparser->ctnstream->tnstream;
        is = tns->istream;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("UNKNOWN ERROR!\n");
        return;
}

    printf("INFO <%d> * <%d> * <%d> * <%d>\n", recognizer->state->exception->line, recognizer->state->exception->charPositionInLine, recognizer->state->exception->index, ((pANTLR3_COMMON_TOKEN) recognizer->state->exception->token)->getCharPositionInLine);
```

}

Every time that I use this grammar to parse some text that has a wrong char, function "recognition_error" does not print the index of the char where the error was found (it just prints garbage like -1 or 0).

How can this grammar and/or C function be fixed to print the correct index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The available error information depends on the type of the exception and the type of token for which it appeared (e.g. virtual nodes generated by tree rewriting). In [MySQL Workbench](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/master/library/mysql.parser/mysql-parser.cpp#L189) I have written error handling code that goes some lengths to find good info to report. Important here is to examine the `exception->type` value and act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Mike! The error handling code in the MySQL Workbench project helped to clarify how to implement it for my project.